# Backups in Brightway: how to use them

Tags: brightway

I am going to make some modifications to methods and the biosphere3 database. As I might break things (I have before), I would like to create backups.

Thankfully, there exist `backup()` methods for just this. For example:

```
myBiosphere = Database('biosphere3')
myBiosphere.backup()
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/technical/bw2data.html), this "Write[s] a backup version of the data to the backups directory." Doing so indeed creates a backup, and the location of this backup is conveniently returned when calling `backup()`.

What I wish to do is to load this backup and replace the database I have broken, if need be. The docs seem to stay silent on this,  though the docs on `serialize` say "filepath (str, optional): Provide an alternate filepath (e.g. for backup)."

How can one restore a database with a saved version?

As a bonus question: how is `increment_version(database, number=None)` called, and how can one use it to help with database management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to `backup` is quite simple:

```
def backup(self):
    """Save a backup to ``backups`` folder.

    Returns:
        File path of backup.

    """
    from bw2io import BW2Package
    return BW2Package.export_obj(self)
```

So you would restore the same as with any `BW2Package`:

```
from brightway2 import *
BW2Package.import_file(filepath)
```

However, if would recommend using `backup_project_directory(project)` and `restore_project_directory(filepath)` instead, as they don't go through an (older) intermediate format.

`increment_version` is only for the single file database backend, and is invoked automatically every time the database is saved. You could add versioning to the sqlite database backend, but this is non-trivial.